# WebAPi - unify error messages format from ApiController and OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api2, owin, fluentvalidation

In my WebAPI project I'm using `Owin.Security.OAuth` to add JWT authentication.
Inside `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` of my OAuthProvider I'm setting errors using below line:

```
context.SetError("invalid_grant", "Account locked.");
```

this is returned to client as:

```
{
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "Account locked."
}
```

after user gets authenticated and he tries to do "normal" request to one of my controllers he gets below response when model is invalid (using FluentValidation):

```
{
  "message": "The request is invalid.",
  "modelState": {
    "client.Email": [
      "Email is not valid."
    ],
    "client.Password": [
      "Password is required."
    ]
  }
}
```

Both requests are returning `400 Bad Request`, but sometimes You must look for `error_description` field and sometimes for `message`

[I was able to create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41481246/apicontroller-extension-method-cant-access-responsemessage) custom response message, but this only applies to results I'm returning.

My question is: is it possible to replace `message` with `error` in response that is returned by `ModelValidatorProviders` and in other places?

I've read about `ExceptionFilterAttribute` but I don't know if this is a good place to start. FluentValidation shouldn't be a problem, because all it does is adding errors to `ModelState`.

**EDIT:**
Next thing I'm trying to fix is inconsistent naming convention in returned data across WebApi - when returning error from `OAuthProvider` we have `error_details`, but when returning `BadRequest` with `ModelState` (from `ApiController`) we have `modelState`. As You can see first uses `snake_case` and second `camelCase`.

Comment: When you create your HttpError object, why are you using custom properties? The HttpError class has properties which mimic yours: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.httperror(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: @returnsvoid sorry for late reply. `HttpError` has `Message` and `MessageDescription` but when using `SetError` in `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider` You set `Error` and `ErrorDescription`. I'd like to have same name for error property (in can be Error od Message, it doesn't matter) so when I return information that something went wrong user will always check single property. Hope this clarify my question a bit

Comment: Are you using customized OAuthProvider?

Comment: @JeffreyA.Gochin Yes, I've build mine based on http://bitoftech.net/2014/10/27/json-web-token-asp-net-web-api-2-jwt-owin-authorization-server/

Comment: Is someone is giving me down votes then please write why. I'd like to improve my questions, but without knowing whats wrong with them I can't do that.

Comment: @Misiu in my opinion this inconsistency is justified and made on purpose due to OAauth2 specificiation and specific error format which OAuth2 authorization servers should return. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-5.2

Comment: @DarjanBogdan I'm aware of that. I don't mind `error` and `error_details`, but I'd like to replace `message` with `error` when for example You get 401 or Your ModelSTate is invalid and You return `BadRequest(ModelState)`

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATED ANSWER (Use Middleware)**

Since the Web API original delegating handler idea meant that it would not be early enough in the pipeline as the OAuth middleware then a custom middleware needs to be created...

```
public static class ErrorMessageFormatter {

    public static IAppBuilder UseCommonErrorResponse(this IAppBuilder app) {
        app.Use<JsonErrorFormatter>();
        return app;
    }

    public class JsonErrorFormatter : OwinMiddleware {
        public JsonErrorFormatter(OwinMiddleware next)
            : base(next) {
        }

        public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context) {
            var owinRequest = context.Request;
            var owinResponse = context.Response;
            //buffer the response stream for later
            var owinResponseStream = owinResponse.Body;
            //buffer the response stream in order to intercept downstream writes
            using (var responseBuffer = new MemoryStream()) {
                //assign the buffer to the resonse body
                owinResponse.Body = responseBuffer;

                await Next.Invoke(context);

                //reset body
                owinResponse.Body = owinResponseStream;

                if (responseBuffer.CanSeek && responseBuffer.Length > 0 && responseBuffer.Position > 0) {
                    //reset buffer to read its content
                    responseBuffer.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                }

                if (!IsSuccessStatusCode(owinResponse.StatusCode) && responseBuffer.Length > 0) {
                    //NOTE: perform your own content negotiation if desired but for this, using JSON
                    var body = await CreateCommonApiResponse(owinResponse, responseBuffer);

                    var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body);

                    var mediaType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(owinResponse.ContentType);
                    using (var customResponseBody = new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, mediaType.MediaType)) {
                        var customResponseStream = await customResponseBody.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                        await customResponseStream.CopyToAsync(owinResponseStream, (int)customResponseStream.Length, owinRequest.CallCancelled);
                        owinResponse.ContentLength = customResponseStream.Length;
                    }
                } else {
                    //copy buffer to response stream this will push it down to client
                    await responseBuffer.CopyToAsync(owinResponseStream, (int)responseBuffer.Length, owinRequest.CallCancelled);
                    owinResponse.ContentLength = responseBuffer.Length;
                }
            }
        }

        async Task<object> CreateCommonApiResponse(IOwinResponse response, Stream stream) {

            var json = await new StreamReader(stream).ReadToEndAsync();

            var statusCode = ((HttpStatusCode)response.StatusCode).ToString();
            var responseReason = response.ReasonPhrase ?? statusCode;

            //Is this a HttpError
            var httpError = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HttpError>(json);
            if (httpError != null) {
                return new {
                    error = httpError.Message ?? responseReason,
                    error_description = (object)httpError.MessageDetail
                    ?? (object)httpError.ModelState
                    ?? (object)httpError.ExceptionMessage
                };
            }

            //Is this an OAuth Error
            var oAuthError = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(json);
            if (oAuthError["error"] != null && oAuthError["error_description"] != null) {
                dynamic obj = oAuthError;
                return new {
                    error = (string)obj.error,
                    error_description = (object)obj.error_description
                };
            }

            //Is this some other unknown error (Just wrap in common model)
            var error = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
            return new {
                error = responseReason,
                error_description = error
            };
        }

        bool IsSuccessStatusCode(int statusCode) {
            return statusCode >= 200 && statusCode <= 299;
        }
    }
}
```

...and registered early in the pipeline before the the authentication middlewares and web api handlers are added.

```
public class Startup {
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) {

        app.UseResponseEncrypterMiddleware();

        app.UseRequestLogger();

        //...(after logging middle ware)
        app.UseCommonErrorResponse();

        //... (before auth middle ware)

        //...code removed for brevity
    }
}
```

This example is just a basic start. It should be simple enough able to extend this starting point.

Though in this example the common model looks like what is returned from OAuthProvider, any common object model can be used.

Tested it with a few In-memory Unit Tests and through TDD was able to get it working.

```
[TestClass]
public class UnifiedErrorMessageTests {
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task _OWIN_Response_Should_Pass_When_Ok() {
        //Arrange
        var message = "\"Hello World\"";
        var expectedResponse = "\"I am working\"";

        using (var server = TestServer.Create<WebApiTestStartup>()) {
            var client = server.HttpClient;
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            var content = new StringContent(message, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            //Act
            var response = await client.PostAsync("/api/Foo", content);

            //Assert
            Assert.IsTrue(response.IsSuccessStatusCode);

            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            Assert.AreEqual(expectedResponse, result);
        }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public async Task _OWIN_Response_Should_Be_Unified_When_BadRequest() {
        //Arrange
        var expectedResponse = "invalid_grant";

        using (var server = TestServer.Create<WebApiTestStartup>()) {
            var client = server.HttpClient;
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            var content = new StringContent(expectedResponse, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            //Act
            var response = await client.PostAsync("/api/Foo", content);

            //Assert
            Assert.IsFalse(response.IsSuccessStatusCode);

            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<dynamic>();

            Assert.AreEqual(expectedResponse, (string)result.error_description);
        }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public async Task _OWIN_Response_Should_Be_Unified_When_MethodNotAllowed() {
        //Arrange
        var expectedResponse = "Method Not Allowed";

        using (var server = TestServer.Create<WebApiTestStartup>()) {
            var client = server.HttpClient;
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            //Act
            var response = await client.GetAsync("/api/Foo");

            //Assert
            Assert.IsFalse(response.IsSuccessStatusCode);

            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<dynamic>();

            Assert.AreEqual(expectedResponse, (string)result.error);
        }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public async Task _OWIN_Response_Should_Be_Unified_When_NotFound() {
        //Arrange
        var expectedResponse = "Not Found";

        using (var server = TestServer.Create<WebApiTestStartup>()) {
            var client = server.HttpClient;
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            //Act
            var response = await client.GetAsync("/api/Bar");

            //Assert
            Assert.IsFalse(response.IsSuccessStatusCode);

            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<dynamic>();

            Assert.AreEqual(expectedResponse, (string)result.error);
        }
    }

    public class WebApiTestStartup {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) {

            app.UseCommonErrorMessageMiddleware();

            var config = new HttpConfiguration();
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            app.UseWebApi(config);
        }
    }

    public class FooController : ApiController {
        public FooController() {

        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult Bar([FromBody]string input) {
            if (input == "Hello World")
                return Ok("I am working");

            return BadRequest("invalid_grant");
        }
    }
}
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER (Use DelegatingHandler)**

Consider using a `DelegatingHandler`

Quoting from an  article found online.

> Delegating handlers are extremely useful for cross cutting concerns.
>   They hook into the very early and very late stages of the
>   request-response pipeline making them ideal for manipulating the
>   response right before it is sent back to the client.

This example is a simplified attempt at the unified error message for `HttpError` responses

```
public class HttpErrorHandler : DelegatingHandler {

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        return NormalizeResponse(request, response);
    }

    private HttpResponseMessage NormalizeResponse(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpResponseMessage response) {
        object content;
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode && response.TryGetContentValue(out content)) {

            var error = content as HttpError;
            if (error != null) {

                var unifiedModel = new {
                    error = error.Message,
                    error_description = (object)error.MessageDetail ?? error.ModelState
                };

                var newResponse = request.CreateResponse(response.StatusCode, unifiedModel);

                foreach (var header in response.Headers) {
                    newResponse.Headers.Add(header.Key, header.Value);
                }

                return newResponse;
            }

        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

Though this example is very basic, it is trivial to extend it to suit your custom needs.

Now it is just a matter of adding the handler to the pipeline

```
public static class WebApiConfig {
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) {

        config.MessageHandlers.Add(new HttpErrorHandler());

        // Other code not shown...
    }
}
```

> Message handlers are called in the same order that they appear in
>   **MessageHandlers** collection. Because they are nested, the response message travels in the other direction. That is, the last handler is
>   the first to get the response message.
>
> Source: [HTTP Message Handlers in ASP.NET Web API](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/http-message-handlers)

Comment: Thank You so much for reply. I'll try that right away. In my app I'm using Middleware to log requests and responses. If I add DelegatingHandler will it work before Middleware or after? Inside Middleware Invoke method I'm getting all parameters from request, then I call `Next.Invoke` and I'm getting all parameters from response. Ideally I'd like that DelegatingHandler to modify response before I log it.

Comment: All depends on the order in which you register your handlers and middleware. you would thus need to register it after the logging middleware so that the log gets the response after the handler on the way out the pipeline.

Comment: Best thing I can do is add Your code and check if everything will work as expected. I'll get back to You as soon as I check this out. Hopefully my middlewares will work fine.

Comment: This almost works great. I've added Your code and I can confirm that it is replacing content returned by ApiController, but I'm unable to access response returned by `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider` when using `context.SetError`. Can DelegatingHandler access that response?

Comment: My middleware is able to access content returned by OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider, but even when I registered DelegatingHandler after my middleware I can't get that response in DelegatingHandler.

Comment: @Misiu, the delegating handler is probably not early enough in the pipeline to intercept the OAuth requests. That means that a custom middleware that does the same or similar to what I have above would need to be created.

Comment: @Misiu check updated answer. tested it with mvc4-mvc5 webapi2 and they all worked. Still need to verify how it handles OAuth with some more tests but I am confident in the design.

Comment: Sorry for such late response. I'll try Your updated answer tomorrow. Hopefully everything will work fine

Comment: `OwinMiddleware` has one thing missing, `DelegatingHandler` has so much easier way of modifying response and getting current content as class. With `OwinMiddleware` You must do all manually.

Comment: That is the trade off between the two ways of doing it.

Comment: The major advantage with the middleware is that it can be placed a lot earlier in the pipeline.

Comment: I have a `DelegatingHandler` to log responses and it works for all controllers, except the `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider`, it sucks that I need to create another middleaware to log responses from this class

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to replace message with error in response that is
>   returned by ModelValidatorProviders

We may use overloaded [SetError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn343603(v=vs.113).aspx#M:Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.BaseValidatingContext%601.SetError(System.String)) to do it otherwise, replace error with message.

```
BaseValidatingContext<TOptions>.SetError Method (String)
```

**Marks this context as not validated by the application and assigns various error information properties. HasError becomes true and IsValidated becomes false as a result of calling.**

```
string msg = "{\"message\": \"Account locked.\"}";
context.SetError(msg); 
Response.StatusCode = 400;
context.Response.Write(msg);
```

Comment: Thank You for such fast reply, but that's not what I meant. `OAuthGrantCustomExtensionContext.SetError` is returning correct response (it has `error` and `error_details` fields). What I need is to return `BadRequest` from `ApiController`, but instead of `message` field in returned JSON I'd like to have `error` field. Hope this clarify my question a bit.